# Call to member function error in CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, model, controller

I'm writing a code which use ajax to delete a specific record in the table. But every time I try to delete a record, it gives me the following error.

> Fatal error:  Call to a member function delete_specific_record() on a non-object in **C:\xampp\htdocs\abcsystem\application\controllers\fuel_types.php** on line **118**

I tried almost everything on the internet as a solution and I'm still getting nowhere. I will add the relevant code blocks for reference.

In JS,

```
//this function will run when fuel delete button is pressed
$("#fueltypes .delete").click(function(event)
{
    //prevent default action being triggered
    event.preventDefault();

    //store relevant data fields to variables
    var base_url    = $("#base_url").val();
    var fuelTypeId  = $(this).siblings("input[type=hidden]").val();

    //create the data streem
    datastreem = ({fuelTypeId:fuelTypeId});

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:base_url+"index.php/fuel_types/ajax_delete_fuel_type",
        data:datastreem,
        success:function(response)
        {
            if(response==1)
            {
                alert("Fuel type deleted");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Fuel type deletion failed");
            }
        }
    })

});
```

In controller(fuel_types.php),

```
class Fuel_types extends CI_Controller
{

    //this function will run when admin try to delete a fuel type
    public function ajax_delete_fuel_type()
    {
        //save ajax sent data into variables
        $fuelTypeId = $this->input->post("fuelTypeId");

        //load vehicle model
        $this->load->model("Vehicles_model");

        //create the recordId array
        $recordId = array('fuel_type_id' => $fuelTypeId);

        //call the function to check if record exists
        $results = $this->Vehicles_model->get_specific_record($recordId);

        //if records available 
        if(($results->num_rows)>0)
        {
            echo "0";
        }
        //if no record is available in the vehicle table
        else
        {                
            //load fuel type model
            $this->load->model("Fuel_types_model");

            //create the recordId array
            $recordId = array('fuel_type_id' => $fuelTypeId);

            //call function to delete records in the model
            $delResults = $this->Fuel_types_model->delete_specific_record($recordId);

            //if record deletion is successful
            if($delResults>0)
            {
                echo("1");
            }
            //if it fails
            else
            {
                echo("0");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and finally at the model(Fuel_types_model.php),

```
class Fuel_types_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //this function will delete record(s) depend on the recordId
    public function delete_specific_record($delRecordId)
    {
        $this->db->where($delRecordId);
        $this->db->delete("fuel_types");

        $delResults = $this->db->affected_rows();

        return $delResults;
    }

}
```

I'm really confused without knowing what I have done wrong. FYI, I have autoloaded database in config/autoload.php file.

I have only included relevant functions of the controller and the model. Other functions which are associate with this controller and model - such as data retrieval and update functions are working just fine. Only problem is

```
   //call function to delete records in the model
   $delResults = $this->Fuel_types_model->delete_specific_record($recordId);
```

this line.

---

(Edit) FYI, I have below included the complete error message

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message:  Undefined property:
>   Fuel_types::$fuel_types_model
>
> Filename:
>   controllers/fuel_types.php
>
> Line Number: 118
>
> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function
>   delete_specific_record() on a non-object in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\abcsystem\application\controllers\fuel_types.php**
>   on line **118**

Comment: Try changing $this->Fuel_types_model to $this->fuel_types_model (all lower case

Comment: @dakshinasd you're sure that model isn't in a subfolder, yes?

Comment: @Mudshark Yes. Model is in application/model folder. (Not in a subfolder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your model function name change delete_specific_record to  remove or other some name
or call in controller , it really works , I have the same problem but after change it resolve,don't use delete keyword  in function & try this function

```
public function remove($id)
 {

 $this->db->where('id',$id);// passing your column name,value
   $this->db->delete('fuel_types');
    $newdata = array(
      'msg'  => 'Deleted  Successfully');
       $session=$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
       return true;
 }
```

Try this,it really works

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller:

```
if($results->num_rows() > 0)
```

instead of:

```
if(($results->num_rows)>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a method named `delete_specific_record` in your model, but you call a method with the same name from your controller. You can't instantiate two methods with the same names in PHP. What happens when you change one of the names?

Comment: He loads the Fuel_types_model class in his controller, then proceeds to use one of its methods. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Yet the error states that he's calling a function called delete_specific_record in the fueul_type controller, not the model. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I tried even calling other functions which are working fine at the same line.

Ex:- $this->Fuel_types_model->get_all_records();

Still I'm getting the same error expect for the changed function name.

Comment: Hold on, let's see what the problem is exactly. The error indicates that the variable $delRecords isn't part of an object. Can you show me exactly where you instantiate $delRecords?